# Android: openaphid/android flip white flashes issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, flipview, flipboard

I am using openaphid flipview library for flipping animation in my application. Everything is working fine but there is a white flash coming when I flip forward. Backwards is working fine. I think no support is now available from the developers. Has anyone fixed this issue?

I already tried everything mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip/issues/52) but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.Somewhat fixed the issue. Will post it here. Delay the handler in hideFlipAnimation() method and it somewhat fixes the flash issue. Not a very clean approach but works for now until a more stable fix is found.

```
private void hideFlipAnimation() {
if (inFlipAnimation) {
  inFlipAnimation = false;

  updateVisibleView(bufferIndex);

  if (onViewFlipListener != null) {
    onViewFlipListener.onViewFlipped(bufferedViews.get(bufferIndex), adapterIndex);
  }

  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      if (!inFlipAnimation) {
        cards.setVisible(false);
        surfaceView.requestRender(); //ask OpenGL to clear its display
      }
    }
  },200);
}
```

}

Comment: the answer doesn't change anything